# QGIS 2.6 python PlugIn Error : NameError: global name 'QMessageBox' is not defined . any idea ? this use to work in QGIS 2.4

Tags: python, qgis-plugins

I am wondering why is this code not working ?

```
 def run(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"Ok", "You pressed F7")
```

NameError: global name 'QMessageBox' is not defined

I trying to make a Plugin in QGIS 2.6 using python. How can in show a message box in new QGIS 2.6 ?

Comment: there are two question. first and related to the subject can have the answer as: did you imported the QMessageBox from PyQt.QtGui ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Luigi . i was missing the import thing i did nor realized it as the way the error was it sounded it says the variable has to be defined rather than the class is not recognized or missing. These people should work on error messages .

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox
```